# Pure CSS HTML5 Progress Element Animation

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to animate HTML5 progress Element just with CSS?
I know how to do it with JS. I was wondering of it is possible with CSS only.

```
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is indeed:

```js
// The value needs to change for the animation to trigger of course
setTimeout(function () {
   document.getElementsByTagName('progress')[0].value = 100; 
});
```

```css
progress {
 appearance: none;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1rem;
 border: 0;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
 background: lightgray;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
 background: #06c;
 transition: width 2.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<progress value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

You'll have to look into the Mozilla/IE pseudo element names though.

Edit: Without changing the value some way the element of course won't move. So I guess you have to use JS to change it, but the animation itself is handled completely by CSS.

Comment: His question asked for pure HTML/CSS no JS however.

Comment: I'm only using the JS to trigger the animation? The point is that the value element can be animated. Some way the value attribute needs to change for the animation to trigger of course.

Comment: I totally understand, I figured he knew this method but was wondering if there was a way to purely animate without help from JS.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I didn't even consider that tbh. Perhaps one could use a CSS animation to change the value element's (`::-webkit-progress-value`) `width`? It would be a bit weird though because the width is supposed to be set with the `value` attribute - not with CSS.

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying. I sort of slapped together a solution I posted in another answer that takes advantage of CSS `@keyframes`

Comment: Thank you @powerbuoy It seems you are replacing the progress element with a background that is then extended. I was looking for a solution for the progress element itself and not a replacement.

Comment: @erosman I'm not sure where you'd get that idea because I'm definitely not replacing anything. As you should be able to see in my code it's a pure `<progress>` element and nothing more.

Comment: @powerbuoy .. the `appearance: none;` caused it to not look like a progress bar and then the width of background is animated and increased.This is the same as using an arbitrary div to represent a progress bar.

Comment: Except that it's still a progress element?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you can tweak this a bit, I just threw it together from a code sample... But I think this sort of qualifies?

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
    position :relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    from   {width: 0px;}
    to  {width: 500px;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: But that way you can't control it's progress with javascript, transition seems to be a better candidate than animation here

Comment: Right, I understand that, but OP asked for a solution that doesn't involve JS so this is what I came up with.

Comment: Thank you @Reed but I was specifically interested in  HTML5 progress Element

Comment: @PhilCollins .. How can it be clearer when it says "HTML5 Progress Element Animation" and not some div representing a progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

Is it impossible to animate HTML5 progress element just with CSS because you need to manipulate pseudo elements with don't work with animation, although you can animate parent element to make it look like progress animation.

```html
 <style>
    .progress-container{
      background: lightgray;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 300px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      animation: moveInRight 3s ease-in 1s ;
     }
    progress{
     width:100%;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 25px; 
    }

    progress[value] {
     vertical-align: middle;
     -moz-appearance: none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     appearance: none;
     border: none;
     }

    progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    @keyframes moveInRight {
      0%{
      text-indent: -100%;
      }

      100% {
       text-indent: 0;
      }
}
   </style>
    <div class="progress-container"><progress max="100" value="70"> 
    </progress> 
    </div>
```